# SharePoint Foundation 2013 - Master Page 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: c#, sharepoint, http-status-code-404, master-pages

I hope this is right place to ask question. I tried use sosial msdn, but it seems that msdn forum is dead. I have small problem with Master Page. I have created Web Template and Master Page. When I create new site collection and I try access to it (`http://win2008r2/sites/Test`), it throws me error that: "404 NOT FOUND".

However, when I check MasterPage gallery: `http://win2008r2/sites/Test/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx`

I can find my Demo.master . When I check Site Collection Features, I can see that my Master Page feature is active. I checked the logs and this was only thing what I found: *Failure when fetching document. 0x80070002*

I have set **Web Template scope to farm** and I have set **Master Page scope to site**.

I try to solve problem using google and I tried different guides but no I cannot get it work. Can anyone please help me?

Here is Element.xml:

```
<Module Name="MyMasterPage" List="116" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
    <File Path="MyMasterPage\Demo.master" Url="Demo.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
    </File>
  </Module>
```

Here is event receiver:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
            {
                using (SPWeb _web = ((SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent).RootWeb)
                {
                    Uri _siteMaster = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/_catalogs/masterpage/Demo.master", _web.Url));
                    _web.MasterUrl = _siteMaster.AbsolutePath;
                    _web.CustomMasterUrl = _siteMaster.AbsolutePath;
                    _web.Update();
                }
            });
        }

        public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            SPSite curSite = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent;
            SPWeb curWeb = curSite.RootWeb;
            Uri masterUri = new Uri(curWeb.Url + "/_catalogs/masterpage/v4.master");
            curWeb.MasterUrl = masterUri.AbsolutePath;
            curWeb.CustomMasterUrl = masterUri.AbsolutePath;
            curWeb.Update();
        }
```

If you want to see more of my code to solve this problem, please feel free to ask, so I put more code up. ;)

Comment: ONet.xml file, I add my Master Page: <SiteFeatures><Feature ID="034a0d23-039e-480d-8aa7-1dee8d60e53f"/></SiteFeatures>

Comment: At this point, I no longer have any ideas to fix the problem. So if anyone knows at least something, so better than nothing.

Comment: Do not dispose SPWeb objects from SPSite.RootWeb.

Comment: Why do you think that problem is in master page? 404 not found in most cases means that page not found. So maybe your web template default page is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets! Problem was that I had named my default.aspx to MySite.aspx and it didn't work. When I created it again and I keep default.aspx name it worked! Well now I have to find way to change that default.aspx name =)